# Why am I getting class cast exception when I reference AppBarLayout and try to get it's LayoutParams using AppBarLayout.LayoutParams?

Tags: android, classcastexception, android-appbarlayout, layoutparams

I am trying to get the Layout Params of **AppBarLayout** but I am getting this error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams

**activity_scrolling.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_scrollview"/> 

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**ScrollingActivity.java**

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
                             AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener{


ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

static boolean toolbarOpen = true;
int lastPosition = 0;
float toolbarThreshhold = 0.3f;

ConstraintSet constraintSet_openToolbar = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintSet constraintSet_closeToolbar = new ConstraintSet();

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    /*Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/

    appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_toolbar_layout);

    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
                                      Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

        constraintSet_openToolbar.clone(this, R.layout.toolbar_scrollview);
        constraintSet_closeToolbar.clone(this, 
                                        R.layout.toolbar_scrollview_closed);
        Log.d(ScrollingActivity.class.getSimpleName() 
                                       ,"onAttachedToWindow()");

}

@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout1, int verticalOffset) {

    if (lastPosition == verticalOffset){
        return;
    }

    Log.d(ScrollingActivity.class.getSimpleName() ,"onOffset Entry");

    lastPosition = verticalOffset;
    float progress = Math.abs(verticalOffset / (float)appBarLayout.getHeight());

    Log.d(ScrollingActivity.class.getSimpleName() ,String.valueOf(lastPosition));

    AppBarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout1.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.topMargin = - verticalOffset;
    appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    if (toolbarOpen && progress >  toolbarThreshhold){
        constraintSet_closeToolbar.applyTo(constraintLayout);
        toolbarOpen = false;
    }
    else if (toolbarOpen && progress <  toolbarThreshhold){
        constraintSet_openToolbar.applyTo(constraintLayout);
        toolbarOpen = true;
    }
}
```

}

I am getting the error in this line (inside **onOffsetChanged()**)

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) 
      appBarLayout1.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: A `View`'s `LayoutParams` are its parent's type, not its own. Your `AppBarLayout` is in a `CoordinatorLayout`, so it has `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: I tried using this code
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =                
          (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout1.getLayoutParams();
there was no error. Thank you @MikeM.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `LayoutParams` of the `CoordinatorLayout` because the `AppBarLayout` is a child of the `CoordinatorLayout` in your layout xml.

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout1.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: This code gives Incompatible type. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: @KavinRajuS I have fixed the incompatible types `Sander`'s answer, check it now

Comment: Woops, my bad. Thanks @VladyslavMatviienko.

Comment: Oh... Okay Will check it